# How to use SSH to create SOCKS server on remote side?

Tags: ssh, socks

I can create a SOCKS proxy on the local side of an SSH connection using `-D`
but is there a way to create a proxy on the remote side?  If not, why not?
`-L` and `-R` do port forwarding on the local and remote side respectively.
I can't see why remote SOCKS proxying would not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about such an option of ssh, but you can get creative and combine -R and -D in two ssh commands like:

```
ssh -D 4711 localhost&
ssh -R 4711:localhost:4711
```

Of course you can use any existing SOCKS proxy instead of the first line.

Comment: That's clever.  I like it!